# Sampling in the Compute Shader not working

Tags: directx11, hlsl

I'm trying to sample a image in the compute shader.

My code is

```
    [numthreads(1, N, 1)]
void VertBlurCS(int3 groupThreadID : SV_GroupThreadID,
                int3 dispatchThreadID : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{

    float4 test = gDiffuseMap.SampleLevel(samAnisotropic,0,0);
    gOutput[dispatchThreadID.xy] = test;
}
```

I'm getting one solid color.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: I think compute shaders are fundamentally broken / don't behave how we would expect ... http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116323/how-do-i-build-a-3d-array-result-set-from-a-compute-shader-in-unity

Comment: The input params are uint3 I believe what are the other variable types?

Comment: @Wardy No, select isn't broken. Don't bring your overly verbose and floundering discussion into other questions.

Comment: What type is `gDiffuseMap` and is it properly bound according to a graphics debugger? Does the debug runtime for Direct3D give you any diagnostics?

Comment: lol @LarsViklund when did I say select was broken? I said compute shaders are broken (at least from a tooling point of view) ... it seems that there is no current way to confirm that the behavior is as expected since the unity framework puts itself between you and the tooling effectively breaking the chain from VS to the compute code otherwise you could follow microsoft advice and simply step through it. In other words it'll either produce the right result or it won't and so far no1 has a viable solution for looking at the raw data generated short of creating a DX project outside of unity.

Comment: @Wardy I was referring to the hopefully well known section in _The Pragmatic Programmer_ that bears that title. See [this article on CodingHorror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/) for a summary. Blaming upstream functionality more often than not just results in the blamer looking silly.

Comment: This question is not about Unity. As for your troubles, you can almost always instrument your project with vspix, RenderDoc, CodeXL, nSight, etc.

Comment: not sure why i thought it was a unity question, yeh instrumentation is where I was hoping to go in my case I can't because unity has issues ... pita

Answer (score 3):

You are sampling from the same location on the texture for every output, therefore the output is a single colour.

See the documentation for [SampleLevel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509699%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

A fix would look something like this:

`float2 uv = float2(dispatchThreadID.xy) / float2(textureWidthHeight);
float4 test = gDiffuseMap.SampleLevel( samAnisotropic, uv, 0 );`